# Dynamic Title for Graphs - Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

So, I have a line graph with the title: "MTTR OOS FIOPTICS MONTHLY TRENDING". Now, I have three filters I am using:

1. Date (Slider that has months from 01/2021 to 10/2022)
2. CO / CR (Only two options)
3. BUS / RES (Only two options)

I have the below code used for my Dynamic Title which is only pulling from number 2 CO/CR

```
Chart Title Fioptics = IF(
ISFILTERED( MTTR[comp_offer_cust_req] ),
CONCATENATEX(
    VALUES( MTTR[comp_offer_cust_req] ),
    MTTR[comp_offer_cust_req],
    ", ",
    MTTR[comp_offer_cust_req], ASC
),
"MTTR OOS FIOPTICS MONTHLY TRENDING")
```

So, when no filter is selected my title just says "MTTR OOS FIOPTICS MONTHLY TRENDING". But once I click on the filter for CO/CR it changes it to say only CO or only CR. Is there a way to have the original title stay after selecting a filter choice and also adding two filters into the title?

So, for example if they pick CR & Bus the title would be something like "BUS CR MTTR OOS Fioptics Monthly Trending". instead of "CR" or "BUS"

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use simply:

```
Chart Title Fioptics =
CONCATENATEX(
    VALUES( MTTR[comp_offer_cust_req] ),
    MTTR[comp_offer_cust_req],
    " ",
    MTTR[comp_offer_cust_req], ASC
) & " MTTR OOS FIOPTICS MONTHLY TRENDING"
```

Comment: Thank you, that answered my initial problem. For the second problem is there a way to add a second filter option to the title from another table mttr[cust_type]? So, have an output of "CO BUS MTTR OOS FIOPTICS MONTHLY TRENDING"? Maybe using UNICHAR(10) or SELECTEDVALUE?